# Add pass to Apple Wallet in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, apple-wallet, pkpass

I am working on integrating adding passes to Apple and Google Wallet in my React Native app. I have got the Google/Android side of things working, but iOS is proving difficult.

My backend side of things is working, and I can generate the passes (`.pkpass` files), and I have tried various libraries such as `react-native-wallet`, `react-native-wallet-manager`, `react-native-passkit-wallet` etc. But when I install these, they don't do anything, and others are asking me to make changes to my Podfile, which doesn't do anything, as I am using Expo.

There doesn't seem to be a lot of support for this. I tried looking into the above libraries to see how they do it, and a lot of them are using `NativeModules` from React Native, and I tried implementing this myyself:

```
const nativeModule = NativeModules.RNPassKit

nativeModule.addPass(base64EncodedPass)
```

But this doesn't do anything, not even an error.

**EDIT**

I have just realised `RNPassKit` was a custom built native module, so I will have to investigate this further.

Comment: Any update to this?

Comment: news about this ?